# Java If Statements - Beginner

Tags: java

So slowly relearning java since I've forgotten all of it from college. I've always wondered if I do my loops in a weird way. I feel there has to be a better way to do loops. I'm pretty sure I always make them far longer than they should be. Anyways I'm following http://programmingbydoing.com/a/twenty-questions.html as it makes me have to google a lot and forces me to come to an understanding rather than just copying code. I'm on this 20 questions part (the link). Here is the code I wrote for it, which works. But is there a better way I could do this? Or what are the other possible ways I could have done this. Does && count as a nested if statement.

edit* Come to think of it. Any critiques at all are welcome. Not necessarily just my loops. If there is anything I am doing the long version of or anything that I'm doing a strange way please let me know.

*edit2. Whoops sorry. Did not know there was a codereview area. Would have posted there if I knew it existed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoQuestions
{
    public static void main (String [] args)


    {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

           String answerOne, answerTwo;

           System.out.println("Two questions game!");
           System.out.println("Think of an object, and I'll try to guess it");

           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("");

           System.out.println("Question 1 - Is it an animal, vegetable, or random thing?");
           answerOne = keyboard.next();

           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("Question 2 - Is it bigger than a breadbox?");
           answerTwo = keyboard.next();

           if (answerOne.equals("animal") && answerTwo.equals("yes"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a moose!");
           }

           else if (answerOne.equals("animal") && answerTwo.equals("no"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a squirrel");
           }

           else if (answerOne.equals("mineral") && answerTwo.equals("yes"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a Camaro");
           }

           else if (answerOne.equals("mineral") && answerTwo.equals("no"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a paper clip");
           }

           else if (answerOne.equals("vegetable") && answerTwo.equals("yes"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a watermelon");
           }

           else if (answerOne.equals("vegetable") && answerTwo.equals("no"))
           {
               System.out.println("You are thinking of a carrot");
           }

           else
           {
                System.out.println("Please make sure you are spelling correctly, no caps");
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not looping. You're just asking two questions and then printing a guess based on those answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please take the time to learn the [difference between loops and conditionals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html). While both structures are used in control flow, they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your conditional statements, but those aren't loops.

Read this for information on loops: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm

For your else case, you should ask the user for another input so they don't have to rerun the program if they make a typo.